# React native video not play video url from server in Ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-video

react-native-video not playing video from a server URL. I am facing this error in Ios.

```
{"error": {"code": -11850, "domain": "AVFoundationErrorDomain", "localizedDescription": "Operation Stopped", "localizedFailureReason": "The server is not correctly configured.", "localizedRecoverySuggestion": ""}, "target": 7225}
```

Solutions that I got from stackover flow and other websites are :

1. To add NSAllowsArbitraryLoads in Info.plist .
2. I Also added the header like this.

```
source={{
    uri: videoFile.uri,
    type: 'mp4',
    headers: {
        'range': bytes=0-'
    }
}}
```

If I add any mp4 video URL from any other website as a static URL in the Video player, then it works fine.

Also working on Android, problem occurs in Ios only.

Any help or solution?

Comment: if other urls work fine it's most likely not an AVPlayer (I assume you use AVPLayer?) setup issue. try play the link in safari browser. is it http or https url?

Comment: AVPlayer requires that your server returns accept-ranges: bytes. Try curl -i xxxx to your mp4 to see if it does return the proper header